# Simple trigger quotas with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Does anyone know if simple triggers, which are set to run under the user's account (not the owner's), count against the total runtime quota for the script's owner? I can't seem to find that specific information anywhere. I know that there is a 1-hour computer time limit on scripts run by triggers, and that any installable triggers would count against that limit for the owner, since they run as the owner. However, I have a spreadsheet which uses some simple triggers to run scripts as the user when they edit or open the spreadsheet. Since the scripts are run as if by the user, it seems logical to me that the runtime would not count against the owner's quota, but I'd like to know for sure. Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Unless a googler decides to step in, I don't think you'll receive a definitive answer. But I suspect it counts against the users' quota, even though the script is running without his permission.

Comment: Just to get a clearer picture, was this spreadsheet created by you and shared with other users so that they can run these scripts?

Comment: The spreadsheet was created by me and shared with other users. Those other users don't run the scripts manually. The scripts have simple onOpen and OnEdit triggers which (to my understanding) run as the user accessing the spreadsheet.